# Importing 360,000 rows into a Global Temporary Table

Tags: sql, excel, import, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having some issues importing a list of numbers into a Global Temporary Table that I created.

**The Problem:** When importing data into a Global Temporary Table, nothing will show up in the desired column even though there is a success message prompt.

**Previous Effort:**

I'm currently using the Data Import Wizard method to do this. I tried importing from a .txt, but it gave me a null error. I tried importing from .xlsx but it gives me the Java heap space error. I tried renaming my .txt file into .tsv file and it said it worked, but no actual data was imported. The Images below shows completion but the end result count in the desired column is still 0.

[image: insert progress]
[image: success message]

What I previously tried was doing insert statements inside of the worksheet using SQL Developer however, I can only copy and paste about 20,000 rows of insert statements into the worksheet at a time. I do not want to have to copy and paste multiple times. However, doing this it will update the table and preserve the data.

**The question has now been answered. See below.**

Comment: The term "created in sql"  doesn't make sense.  SQL is a programming language.

Comment: If you have memory (heap) errors, increase the memory allocation for SQL Developer. You could also put all 360,000 inserts into a script file and run that, but it will be slow. By 'temporary table' do you mean a normal table you've created for this work and will drop later, or an actual global temporary table, whose contents are only available to the session that created them?

Comment: global temporary table.

Comment: Was it created with settings to preserve or delete on commit?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that. When I try to import data from excel would it preserve the data imported or delete? Why would it delete? I'm not an expert.

Comment: [See the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54475). If you didn't specify then commit deletes the rows from the GTT; you can drop and recreate with `on commit preserve rows` instead. You can check the current setting from `user_tables.duration`.

Comment: Oh, well I wouldn't be committing anything and any global temporary tables I created should be removed on exit. I just want to do a comparison and I am only trying to import one column into a global temporary table that I have created. However, when I do nothing is showing up in the specified column that I tell it to import to.

Comment: I posted some pictures to show you what's happening when I use the import wizard to import the data.

Comment: Look at that dialogue message: "Task successful and import committed". The import is automatically committing. With the default GTT settings that will remove the data it just inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a global temporary table is created with an implicit `on commit delete` clause:

```
create global temporary table tblbc (bc number);

Global temporary TABLE created.

select duration from user_tables where table_name = 'TBLBC';

DURATION      
---------------
SYS$TRANSACTION
```

The import is committing, as the dialogue message states. That means that the data is then deleted from the GTT, as that's what the duration is set to. That's the equivalent of doing:

```
insert into tblbc(bc) values (42);

1 row inserted.

commit;

Commit complete.

select * from tblbc;

no rows selected
```

If you redefine the GTT then you will be able to see the imported data after that commit, at least within the same session:

```
drop table tblbc;

Table TBLBC dropped.

create global temporary table tblbc (bc number) on commit preserve rows;

Global temporary TABLE created.

select duration from user_tables where table_name = 'TBLBC';

DURATION      
---------------
SYS$SESSION    

insert into tblbc(bc) values (42);

1 row inserted.

commit;

Commit complete.

select * from tblbc;

        BC
----------
        42
```

You can now compare the data in the GTT with your other tables, again just within that session. Once you end the session the GTT data will be lost.

Comment: Thank you Alex for helping with this. Thank you for being polite and patient with me. In what way can I change my question to make it more clear?

Comment: Well, making it clear that it was a GTT form the start might have helped, and then showing the creation statement DDL for that. The second and third paragraphs mention several things you tried and some issues you had, and it isn't really clear which one you really want to use - the focus of the question is really "I imported from a .tsv file  but the table was empty afterwards - why?" (and a small sample of the content of the file would be good too) but that isn't clear. Or maybe I inferred that was the result you wanted!